# Windows 10 not booting after installing Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dual-boot, 15.04, uefi

I was using Windows 10 in legacy Bios mode. Yesterday I have tried installing Ubuntu 15.04 and the Installation was successful. I have installed Ubuntu in Seperate Partition. I can boot in to Ubuntu, but there is no option for booting in to Windows.

I think Ubuntu is in UEFI mode and Windows was in Legacy BIOS mode. I know I screwed up something.  How to recover my Windows back. I want dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04.

What is the correct procedure?

**output from** `sudo fdisk -l` **is:**

```
root@padhu-Inspiron-3537:/home/padhu# sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x488bcf30

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848 219013119 218294272 104.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       219013120 246376447  27363328    13G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       246388966 976771071 730382106 348.3G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       246388968 871429859 625040892   298G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       871430144 875429887   3999744   1.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       875431936 976771071 101339136  48.3G 83 Linux

Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

**Output of** `os-prober` **command**

```
root@padhu-Inspiron-3537:/home/padhu# os-prober
/dev/sda1:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows:chain
root@padhu-Inspiron-3537:/home/padhu#
```

Comment: Have you tried to convert your disk to GPT?

Comment: @SonNheo Nope. I didnt try any. I am new to this. can you help me

Comment: I'm not sure if it might help, but it's not a good idea to run dual-boot on Legacy mode. I suggest that you should try to boot repair first.

Comment: ***DO NOT*** attempt to convert the disk from MBR to GPT form!!! That will render Windows unbootable! (Yes, I know you're having trouble booting Windows now, but the conversion would be like jumping into a swimming pool filled with rusty nails in an effort to heal a scratch.) To give an answer that's more than a guess, we need more information. Please run the [Boot Info Script,](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) post the `RESULTS.txt` file it produces to [a pastebin site,](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL to your document here.

Comment: Tried Updating the Grub and Windows is booting fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this issue with this tip from ubuntu.

Link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

I hope it will fix your problem!

Cheers

Comment: Np :) hope it will help!