# Windows 10 laptop returns to boot menu repeatedly after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I have Windows 10 and before I setup Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit I disabled fast startup from battery settings. Then I started to setup my Ubuntu. I give it hard drive and 2 GB swap and I pressed Install. After install I want to play a game on my Windows 10.

The problem is when I restart my laptop and select Windows 10 from the boot menu it didn't do anything, just a black screen and returned to my boot menu over and over again and I can't access Windows.

P.S : I Can access to windows Folder From ubuntu

Comment: er, are you sure you didn't accidentally wipe windows? Can you see a windows partition from ubuntu?

Comment: I can see partition from ubuntu and i can access to the folders

Comment: Rather than guessing, best to see details on how you installed: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can access your windows 10 drive from within Ubuntu by clicking the drive icons on the unity bar.

If you can access them, setup grub again

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then, reboot.

Comment: okay after reboot what i have to do open windows or open ubuntu ?

Comment: I open the terminal and I type :

sudo update-grub

after reboot I try to open lunch windows 10 but the same problem black screen and return to the boot menu :(

Comment: Sounds like you damaged the boot-part of Windows somehow :/ How did you install? Manually or what did you choose during installation ?

In Ubuntu, open gparted (sudo apt-get install gparted, if you dont have it) and maybe take a screenshot of the partitions so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

### Update GRUB

Try entering this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

### Use the Boot-Repair tool

For more information, see the [Community Wiki page.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

**Installing Boot-Repair**

Use the below commands to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

**Launching Boot-Repair**

- Use the launcher from the Dash...

... or ...

- Enter the command below in a terminal:

  > boot-repair

---

### Other information

Thought this was worth mentioning...

> DO NOT attempt to convert the disk from MBR to GPT form!!! That will
>   render Windows unbootable! (Yes, I know you're having trouble booting
>   Windows now, but the conversion would be like jumping into a swimming
>   pool filled with rusty nails in an effort to heal a scratch.) To give
>   an answer that's more than a guess, we need more information. Please
>   run the Boot Info Script, post the RESULTS.txt file it produces to a
>   pastebin site, and post the URL to your document here 
>   – Rod Smith

Comment - "[Windows 10 not booting after installing Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688518/windows-10-not-booting-after-installing-ubuntu-15-04)"

---

Comment: i can't understand anything you say except 

 The asker solved a non-bootable Win10 after he updated GRUB.
sudo update-grub

Comment: Have you figured out a solution @AbdallahMohamed ? If not, can I offer more help?